# Issue with namespaced Url Resolution in Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-views, url-routing

I'm having an issue with url resolution in an invitation app that I'm writing.

Essentially I have a redirect view which redirects an authenticated user to either a dashboard if they are staff, or to an invitation page if they are not staff. Simple enough right?

However, whether or not the user is staff the user is redirected to the invitation view.

The smoking gun is the value for response.resolver_match which I pulled in one of my unit tests

```
ResolverMatch(func=invitation.views.invitation, args=(), kwargs={'invitation_name': 'dashboard'}, url_name=invitation, app_names=[], nam
espaces=['invitation'])
```

The strangest bit is that if I actually login as a staff member, the browser url is /invitation/dashboard/

Here are my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^invitation/', include("invitation.urls", namespace="invitation")),
url(r'^login-redirect/$', login_redirect, name="login_redirect"),
url(r'^$',
    login,
    {"template_name": "invitation/login.html"},
    name="login"),
]
```

invitation.urls

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'(?P<invitation_name>[\w]+)/$', views.invitation, name="invitation"),
url(r'add-invitation/$', views.add_invitation, name="add_invitation"),
url(r'dashboard/$', views.dashboard, name="dashboard"),
]
```

login_redirect view

```
@login_required
def login_redirect(request):
    if request.user.is_staff:
        return redirect(reverse("invitation:dashboard"))
    else:
        return redirect(
            reverse("invitation:invitation",
            args=[request.user.username]))
```

I'm all out of ideas on this...it's weird. I don't get it.

ANY help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Beware the greedy url...

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'dashboard/$', views.dashboard, name="dashboard"),
    url(r'(?P<invitation_name>[\w]+)/$', views.invitation, name="invitation"),
    url(r'add-invitation/$', views.add_invitation, name="add_invitation"),
]
```

Re-organzing the urls was all it took.